# What is the meaning of the output shape in model.summary of KERAS?

Tags: keras

Below is the RNNs model.

[image]

And In keras, the output shape of the below code is (N,10).

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(RNN(10, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
```

I know that N in the output shape (N,10) is the batch_size.

What I want to know is that '10' is the [image]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `10` is `D_h`. Basically `RNN(units)` denotes that the layer returns the vector `h_t` from the final timestep of the RNN with the size being the number you specify for the `units` parameter, which in this case is `10`. Or in other words, `units` parameter denotes the dimensionality of the output vector of that particular layer.

Comment: Thank you, and I want to ask one more question. In keras, the x_t goes into the RNNs as row vector(1,d)?